# Using List/arrays in JPA Procedure

Tags: java, jpa, data-binding, spring-data-jpa, procedure

I have problem with using @Procedure annotation in my repository with List/array object. When i`m using list in my procedure then i`m getting an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null
```

Or when i`m converting my lsit into array then i`m gettin an error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function my_procedure(bytea) does not exists
```

My Procedure example in Repository Class:
@Procedure(procedureName = "my_procedure")
Boolean myProcedure(List ids);

Is there any option to pass collection object into Repository Query/Procedure annotation?

Comment: i suspect you are trying to call stored procedure please refer this link for more details https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures

Comment: isn`t there any option without using @StoredProcedureParameter? Couse when i`m using many functions in my Repository or when i have many parameters in function then code in Entity is  unreadable  and time-consuming